# Clear contents of rows with date older than today with a button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to put on some Google Function to make that in the title. I'm very beginner but I'm up for the challenge. I managed to make a button that clears the whole range (C5:G102).

But I want now a code that clears that range only for the dates that are older than today.

I have columns with subject, a deadline, description, etc. The whole date goes from column C to G. So when I click the button I want all subjects in that row that already has an older deadline than today, to be cleared out. The dates are in the column D.

Can that be done?

I have only this:

```
function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ADD');
  sheet.getRange('C5:G102').clearContent();
}
```

So, after some trying I came up with this: but it doesn't work...

```
function ClearOlder() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ADD');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var columnD = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var day = 24*3600*1000
  var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);

  for (var i=1; i < columnD.length; i++) {
    var dataday = parseInt(new Date(columnD[i][4]).getTime()/day);
    if (dataday < today) {sheet.getRange(i+1, 4, lastRow, 1).clearContent();}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually compare date directly in javascript. You do not need the `parseInt()` function.

```js
var TEN_DAYS = 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
//             days hrs min   sec   ms

var expiry = new Date() - TEN_DAYS;

var date1 = new Date('2019-02-5');
var date2 = new Date('2019-02-1');
var date3 = new Date('2019-01-25');

console.log(expiry > date1); //Less than 10 days ago
console.log(expiry > date2); //Less than 10 days ago
console.log(expiry > date3); //More than 10 days ago
```

**Updated:** Your columnD selector was off.

```
function clearOlder() { 
  //consider camelCase --> clearOlder() 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 

  var columnD = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues(); //OP updated this to better fit their specific spreadsheet.

  var one_day = 24*3600*1000; 
  var expiry = new Date() - one_day; 

  for (var i=1; i < columnD.length; i++) { 

    var dataday = new Date(columnD[i][0]); 

    if (expiry > dataday) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, 4).clearContent(); //OP updated this to better fit their specific spreadsheet.

    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried but it didn't work.... I guess I don't know where I'm getting into... Tricky thing...

Comment: function clearOlder() { //consider camelCase --> clearOlder()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ADD');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var columnD = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var one_day = 24*3600*1000;
  var expiry = new Date() - one_day;

  for (var i=1; i < columnD.length; i++) {
    var dataday = new Date(columnD[i][4]);
    if (expiry > dataday) {sheet.getRange(i+1, 4, lastRow, 1).clearContent();}
      //dataday is older than one day, clear the cell...
      
    }

  }

Comment: @JottaKz I've updated my answer. You were selecting the incorrect value in columnD[x][x] piece.

Comment: The expiry > dataday should be with < right? Well... it kinda works... but the title in row 4 gets erased also... Damn this thing is hard... I'm doing a try and error but I can't get to work... I have data from C to G columns, and the "input" starts at row 5... if that helps... thank you for your patience and time... :-)

Comment: @JottaKz Sorry it's hard to understand what the layout of your spreadsheet looks like. I can update my answer with the changes that fit your spreadsheet.

Comment: thank you your code worked I just had to do a little twich! I don't know how to promote the answer here... but really, thanks!

Comment: No worries, If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I got it!!!

```html
function clearOlder() { 
  //consider camelCase --> clearOlder() 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 

  var columnD = sheet.getRange(1, 4, sheet.getLastRow(), 5).getValues(); 

  var one_day = 24*3600*1000; 
  var expiry = new Date() - one_day; 

  for (var i=1; i < columnD.length; i++) { 

    var dataday = new Date(columnD[i][0]); 

    if (expiry > dataday) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, 5).clearContent();

    }
  } 
}
```